# Selling the underlying in case a covered call is exercised?

Tags: options, options-assignment, covered-call-writing

If I sell an out-of-the-money covered call and the option becomes in-the-money prior to expiry, then am I forced to sell my underlying at the strike price (assuming the counterparty decides to exercise)?

Or can I simply buy-to-close and keep the underlying?

Comment: Who is this imposter? Why did you change your name/ID from Kaushik ?

Comment: Sorry...people were catching on at work...sorry for the name conflict man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get selected for exercise, your broker will liquidate the whole position for you *most likely*

Talk to your broker.

Comment: Absolutely right. His question is a bit ambiguous, though. Prior to expiry, he can buy the option back, but if it expires in the money, the buyer exercises. Or if a dividend is near expiration, it make be worth it to exercise to trap that as well.